# Frenet frame and application

Tags: mathematics, geometry

I have just been reviewing Frenet Frame math. It is an interesting geometrical issue.

I know that common applications are:

- camera movement along a curve
- tube and ribbons surface

Can someone suggest other interesting applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting. Roller Coaster rides is what came to my mind. You can manipulate a 3D object riding a path in three dimensions.